# c# .Net Can I somehow format a DataSet to send as a repsonse from a website

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, dataset, datatables, httpwebresponse

Scenario:
I have a C# Windows Desktop Application that will request all the Customers in my database.
I validate who they are on the server and query the database server which returns either a datatable or a dataset.
Is there a way to convert/encode this datatable or dataset and send it back as a response?
My plan is then the client application will convert it back into a datatable or dataset and have its way with it!

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

you might want to look into serializing a dataset. (xml version: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). search here and/or msdn for options, especially converting to json.